# Silverlight Listbox update style at runtime

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a listbox control added to my layout as show in the below code snippet.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstFilters" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerCollection, Source={StaticResource VMCustomers}}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="200" Margin="12,20,235,80">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource styleFont}"></HyperlinkButton>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtFilterCount" Text="{Binding ContactNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

  <Style x:Key="styleFont" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have written a style that sets the font family to HyperlinkButton control.
Now i want to set this fontfamily from code behind because i am getting the value at runtime. so how to change it and one more thing i want to do this at the constructor or page load event i.e. i want to set this only once and it should apply for all the items i.e if there are 100 items then it should get applied to all the 100 items. so it makes it faster instead of always binding it any event.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to bind the style to a property of the UserControl using the following XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="styleFont" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" 
        Value="{Binding DataContext.ListFont,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you just need to update the property and the style will reflect the new Font for all the list items.

**Update:**
This answer is only valid for Silverlight 5.

Comment: Hey hie thanks for the reply. I tried the way you suggested but not able to get the code working. Can you just tell me "ListFont" is a property right i am getting error at "AncestorType" it is not available as a relative source in intellisense. if possible can you explain or just share a piece of code so that i have a clear understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to bind the style to a parent property in SL 4 and below.  I found this article to which allows to set bindings of controls but it won't work for styles: http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/